# Apache camel cron error because of Failed to resolve endpoint: cron

Tags: java, cron, apache-camel

I try to use camel with cron expressions. Because i need 3 different things to do with cron expressions, 3 different timings. Daily, monthly and instant check of files in remote. I can not do it with spring batch. So, i chose camel.

```java
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    onException(Exception.class)
        .process(lifeDispatchExceptionProcessor)
        .handled(true)
        .transform()
        .simple("Error reported: ${exception.message} - cannot process this message.");

    from("cron:tab?schedule=0/3 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *")
        .setBody().constant("event")
        .log("${body} faafs")
        .process(documentProcessor);
    
}
```

I added this method as hello world but even this is not working:

> //org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootInitializationException:
> org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: // Failed to create
> route route147: Route(route147)[[From[cron:tab?schedule=0/3 0/1 * 1/1
>
> - ? *]... // because of Failed to resolve endpoint: cron://tab?schedule=0%2F3+0%2F1+*+1%2F1+*+%3F+* due to: No component
>   found with scheme: cron

This is pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jaxp-ri</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.parsers</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quartz2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jaxp-ri</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.parsers</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jaxp-ri</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.parsers</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jaxp-ri</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.parsers</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jaxp-ri</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.parsers</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-bindy</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-crypto</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-kafka</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jaxp-ri</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.parsers</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I want to be able to use cron expressions, so camel will check according to cron expresions. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Camel Doc for [Cron Components](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/cron-component.html), you have to inject dependency `camel-cron` before use.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-cron</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
    <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

---

The cron component available in Camel since version 3.1. For version older than 3.1, you may consider to use [the cron trigger method under quartz2 component](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/quartz2-component.html#_using_cron_triggers).

Comment: It says `Dependency 'org.apache.camel:camel-cron:' not found`

Comment: Probably you are using version older than 3.1, then try the cron trigger method under quartz2